# How to compare two files line by line from particular string in java

Tags: java

I have to compare two files ,line by line from a particular word in both files using java language.

I do not know , how to write a condition. Am trying to compare from line by line. But am unable to compare from the particular String.

The both files has the strings. It should start from a particular string and end comparing to a another particular string. My code is comparing two files line by line. but not from a particular string.

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("s2.txt");  
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);  
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  

            FileInputStream ff1=new FileInputStream("s1.txt");  
            DataInputStream fin=new DataInputStream(ff1);  
            BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));  

            String line1 = null;
            String line2 = null;
            int flag = 1;




            while(
                    (flag == 1) 
                    && ((line1 = br.readLine()) != null)
                    && ((line2 = br1.readLine()) != null)  

                    )
            {

                //if((line1.contains("(Center t)")) && (line2.contains("(Center t )"))) 
                    //&& (line2.contains("(Center t)"))
                    /*&&(line1.endsWith("ID: ")) 
                        && (line2.endsWith(" ID: "))**///)
                //{
                    if(!line1.equalsIgnoreCase(line2))
                        flag = 0;
                //}

            }

            br.close();
            br1.close();
            System.out.println("flag "+flag);
        }
        catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any  

            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());  

        }  
    }
```

My code is comparing two files line by line. How to do from a particular word?
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Two files line by line starting with a particular _word_? That does not really make sense. Can you provide an example and an expected output?

Comment: i have to read two files line by line. Have to compare from a particular string @ fge

Comment: Again: provide an example. Your question is not clear.

Comment: My file1 has 5000lines.. My file 2 has 6000 lines .. i have to compare from a particular word .. if control will reach the word "center " den it should start comparing.. and if it will reach " id " it should stop comparing. how to do?

Comment: How to compare both files from the word ? anyone can help me?

Comment: And then what? Compare all the lines from these frontiers and see if they are equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use StringUtils of Apache Commons Lang:

```
        String subLine1 = StringUtils.substringBetween(line1, "Center t", "ID: ");
        String subLine2 = StringUtils.substringBetween(line2, "Center t", "ID: ");
        if(subLine1 != null && subLine1.equals(subLine2)) {
            //the lines equals between 'Center t' and 'ID: '
            //.....
        }
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/